# window.close() to restrict parent page to refresh

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have opened a dialog box using `jQuery`. In dialog box I have added to code to close when close button is clicked. In this function i have used window.close(). In some cases it refreshes the parent page but i do not want to refresh the parent/caller page. How can I restrict parent page to refresh.

```
if (condition)
{
     window.close();
     return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So `window` refers to a popup/child tab window? I mean, what is the context of this code???

Comment: Yes, it refers to a popup window i.e a aspx page. But it refreshes the parent window caller window. But i don't need to refresh tha parent window.

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() of jquery Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.Is this what you were looking for?.Hope that helps.

Comment: I have done this but with this parent window refreshed. I don't  want to refresh the window.